# why would sql server give me a 2 line output for 1 update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I ran a query:

```
  update activity
  set scheduledforuseridy=749
  where datecompleted is null
  and dateexpired is null
  and scheduledforuseridy=374
  and communityidy=12
```

and the output was:

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(170 row(s) affected)
```

I was expecting just a one line output:

```
(xxx row(s) affected)
```

**Why was there a two line output?**

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: wow yes indeed thanky ou very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a `update` trigger on the table. That's why one output for your UPDATE statement and another for the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
EXEC sp_helptrigger activity
```