# for what reason would I get 2 outputs for 1 update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I ran an update:

```
update a
        set a.scheduledforuseridy=n.[newid]
        from activity a
        join newtable n
        on a.scheduledforuseridy=n.oldid
        and a.prospectidy=n.id
```

and I got:

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(1391 row(s) affected)
```

Could this be because the table was locked in the middle of the update by another thread?

**In what situations would an update cause 2 outputs?**

Comment: FK's with `on update cascade` or triggers ?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it. Trigger without `set nocount on` produces this effect. FK with `on update cascade` has no such effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why would sql server give me a 2 line output for 1 update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072933/why-would-sql-server-give-me-a-2-line-output-for-1-update)

Comment: You asked the same question a couple of months ago.

Comment: Those rowcounts would make me suspect that it's a poorly written trigger too. Seeing a 2 row update cause thousands of other changes is rarely correct.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, as I noticed when tried, last row is showing number of rows updated, and previous is output from trigger. I think that this is because of last one should become `@@ROWCOUNT` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Update Trigger on that table which performs DML will output a message for each statement in it